# Graphic of Backward Euler Method Stability with a specific ODE

Tags: numerical-methods, stability-in-odes, nonlinear-analysis

I have been studying the Backward Euler Method, and I am have having some of problems representing the stability of the method of some particular ODEs.

If I am thinking correctly this method will be stable if the solutions of the ODE are stable, which means that $Re(λ) < 0$ and $h > 0$, (h= step size).

One of my problems is that I don't know how to calculate the sign of the λ of this non-linear equations.

**a)$\ y'=1/(t+y), \quad  y(0) = 1$**

**b)$\ y'=-(1+t)exp(y),\quad  y(0) = 1$**

If there is any positive λ, then a step size big enough will be stable even though it might not be a good representation of the solution?

Or will the solution be automatically unstable if the $Re(λ) > 0$?

Thank you very much, any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the $y$-derivative, as the $λ$ are the eigenvalues of the Jacobian. The idea is that the linearization of the equation has solutions that are locally equivalent to the solutions of the non-linear equation.

In the first example the derivative is $-1/(t+y)^2$, always negative on the domain of the ODE. In the second example the derivative is $-(1+t)\exp(y)$, which is also negative in some neighborhood of the initial point.

In the first example there is an asymptote $y=-1-t$ that the numerical solution should also converge to under a stable method. In the second example there is no asymptote, the solution is falling below all boundaries, the stability of the method has no greater influence on the numerical solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, your intake was much clearer than any of the many sources I investigated! Can you just clarify me, the asymptote in the first example is within the complex plane of λ h? Why is not $y = -t$

Comment: I forgot to mention you.

Comment: In the first equation set $u=y+t$, then $u'=y'+1=\frac{1+u}{u}$. The right side is zero for $u=-1$. The line $y+t=0$ is not in the domain of this ODE.